# Limiting CPU Usage in a Ticker Component in C# .NET 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-1.1

I created a Ticker component (System.Windows.Forms.UserControl) in C# .NET 1.1 using System.Threading.Thread. This ticker will scroll from right to left and reading data from xml feed. This component will be invoked by our main application with videos, and other processes running.

Testing the application without the ticker component consumes CPU maximum of 55%, however, when integrating the Ticker component it goes up as high as 95%.

I also tried using the System.Windows.Forms.Timer but the result was the same.

Parsing of Xml data occurs during initialization of the component only and here is the sample code snippet that will process the ticker to scroll:

```
Thread _mainThread;

private void InitTickerThread() 
{
_panelHeadlines = (Panel) FindControl("panelHeadlines", this);

if(_panelHeadlines != null) 
{
    _textWidth = _panelHeadlines.Size.Width;
}

_locXOffset = 0;

_mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartScrolling));
_mainThread.Name = "Main Ticker Thread";
_mainThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest;
_mainThread.IsBackground = true;
_mainThread.Start();
}

private void StartScrolling() 
{
while(true) 
{
    lock(this)
    {
        _locXOffset -= 1;


        if (_locXOffset < -_textWidth) //If entire ticker content has finished scrolling.
        {
            _locXOffset = 0;
            _partnerCtr = 0;

            Partner p = _arrListPartners[_partnerCtr] as Partner;
            if(p != null) 
            {
                pbPartnerLogo.Image = p.Logo;
                _partnerContentWidth = p.ContentWidth - _offsetToChangeLogo;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            if(_locXOffset < -_partnerContentWidth) 
            {
                _partnerCtr++;

                if(_arrListPartners.Count > 0) 
                {
                    if(_partnerCtr < _arrListPartners.Count) 
                    {
                        Partner p = _arrListPartners[_partnerCtr] as Partner;

                        if(p != null) 
                        {
                            pbPartnerLogo.Image = p.Logo;
                            _partnerContentWidth = p.ContentWidth - _offsetToChangeLogo;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        _panelHeadlines.Location = new Point(_locXOffset, 0);

        Invalidate();

        Thread.Sleep(20);
    }
}
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your background thread is doing work every 20ms, that's 50 times a second. I'd suggest dropping that back dramatically.

Comment: I actually set it to 20ms for it to achieve the scroll speed that is required.

Answer (score 0):

Every 20 milliseconds you are redrawing your entire component. This is very costly. My advice is to increase the sleep, and/or make your code more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the response guys. I set it to 20 milliseconds for it to achieve the scroll speed requirement of the ticker. Any other alternative?

Comment: Yes, make it move more than 1 pixel at a time and reduce the frequency, either that or live with the processor utilisation.

Comment: Is it possible to give some code snippet samples? does this mean that I need to decrease the _locXOffset to probably 2 or higher?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you're updating your UI control by posting messages to foreground UI thread?  (your code sample isn't complete, so I can't really tell)

Comment: The method that is calling InitTickerThread is just parsing the xml data and put each appropriate text to a LinkLabel to make it clickable. The link labels is added to a Windows.Forms.Panel and I add that panel to the control. e.g. this.Controls.Add(pnlTickerItems);